# Remove active class on navigation link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation

this is my HTML menu structure:

```
<div id="footer-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="creative-events-menu" href="#/creative-events"></a></li>
                    <li><a id="creative-ajans-menu" href="#/creative-ajans"></a></li>
                    <li><a id="incentive-travel-menu" href="#/incentive-travel"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="hakkimizda-menu" href="#/hakkimizda"></a></li>
                    <li><a id="haberler-menu" href="#/haberler"></a></li>
                    <li><a id="galeri-menu" href="#/galeri"></a></li>
                    <li><a id="referanslar-menu" href="#/referanslar"></a></li>
                    <li><a id="iletisim-menu" href="#/iletisim"></a></li>
</ul>
                    </ul>
            </div>
```

And i want, add `active` class on active menu and remove when i get another page.

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $('li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest('ul').find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $this.parent().addClass('active');

    });
});

</script>
```

This script add `active` class but don't remove. How can i fix it?

Comment: Is it a typo or do you have `</ul>` twice?

Comment: And you don't have anything between `<a>` and `</a>`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Changing the script this way, works:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('li a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('ul').find('.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        });
    });
  </script>
```

If you wanna add the class to the `<a>`, use this: `$(this).addClass('active');` instead of `$(this).parent().addClass('active');`

#### Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/uyidom/1

---

#### Is it a typo or do you have `</ul>` twice?

Comment: What is the difference? closest selects the closest parent(_regarding to the selector_).

Comment: `closest` and `parent` are different right? Lemme check!

Comment: @undefined Oops sorry, my mistake. Will edit ASAP!

Comment: Thank you. Well, how can add active class to li a? This function add only on li.

Comment: @SlaythernAareonna Changing the script works. Check out the fiddle too!

Comment: @SlaythernAareonna If you wanna add the class to the `<a>`, use this: `$(this).addClass('active');`